# How to display following response using vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

This is my response.. How to display the error message? passwords do not match

```
 {"errors": {"password": ["Passwords donot match"]}, "status": false, "msg": "Validation erro", "error-type": 0}
```

Currently my code is

```
<script>
regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
  data: {
   ..........
    response: {
        message: '',
        status: '',
        state: '',
        errors: '',
    }
  },
methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
         ..............
            $.ajax({
              url: '',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {
               alert(" Success")

            }
              else {
                vm.response = e;
               alert(" Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}
},
});
</script>
```

My html code to display the same is

```
 <p class="error">{{response.errors.password}}</p>
```

Currently i am getting error message as 
["Passwords donot match"]

How to get only message as

Passwords donot match.. so, how can i able to get it.. can anybody help

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
<p class="error">{{response.errors.password[0]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the first element

```
<p class="error">{{response.errors.password[0]}}</p>
```